# latex with vim irritatingly opening new buffer window

Tags: latexmk, vim, vim-latex

I edit my Latex in (g)vim. Now, when I am getting any error in compiling, vim is irritatingly opening the file in a new buffer, and moving to that buffer. For example, say, if I am getting an warning  with `tikz` as
`/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex|| LaTeX Warning: No \author given.`, vim is openning the `tikz.code.tex` file in buffer 2, and moving to buffer 2.

ofcourse you understand, I am not writing for this specific error, which can be corrected easily, but in general, I just want to see the error in quickfix window, below my main window.

Here is the an example:

my minimal

## vimrc:

```
"General "{{{
set nocompatible                     "  because vim is not vi
set ignorecase                       "  Searching ignore case, be smart, highlight match
set smartcase
set hlsearch
set incsearch
"}}}


"Vundle Plugins" {{{
filetype off
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim/
call vundle#begin()
Plugin 'xuhdev/SingleCompile.git'                 " Compilers
Plugin 'syntastic'                                " Syntax checker
Plugin 'vim-flake8'                              " python standard
" Plugin 'ambv/black'
" Plugin 'klen/python-mode'                         " python IDE
Plugin 'vim-scripts/indentpython.vim'             " Python
" Markdown
Plugin 'gerw/vim-latex-suite'
Plugin 'gerw/vim-tex-syntax'
call vundle#end()
filetype plugin indent on
" "}}}

"LANGUAGE SPECIFIC STAFFS{{{
"========================
" MultipleFiles{{{
augroup VIMRC
  autocmd VimEnter,GUIEnter * set visualbell t_vb=
  au BufNewFile,BufRead *.page set  ft=mallard 
  au BufNewFile,BufRead *.page so /usr/share/vim/vim81/indent/xml.vim 
  au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 0 && line("'\"") <= line("$")
        \| exe "normal! g'\"" | endif
augroup END
"}}}
"LaTeX: {{{
augroup FT_LaTex
  let g:tex_flavor = 'latex'
  let g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat = 'pdf'
  let g:syntastic_tex_checkers = ['chktex']
  let g:Tex_ViewRule_pdf = 'evince_dbus.py'
  let g:Tex_Debug = 1
  let g:Tex_DebugLog = 'vim-latex-suite.log'
  au FileType tex inoremap "" ``"<++><esc>4hi
  " au FileType tex  nnoremap <buffer> <Leader>lm :up!<cr>:! latexmk -pdf -quiet --shell-escape %<cr>
  au FileType *.tex set vim=~/bin/vims.py
  au filetype tex syntax region texZone start='\\begin{minted}' end='\\end{minted}'
augroup END
"}}}
"}}}

"BUFFERS  {{{
map <leader>bd :Bclose<cr>      " Close the current buffer
map <leader>ba :1,1000 bd!<cr>  " Close all buffer
nnoremap <F12>    :bn<CR>       " Next buffer
nnoremap <S-F12>  :bp<CR>       " Previous buffer
"Opens a new tab with the current buffer's path
"Super useful when editing files in the same directory
map <leader>te :badd <c-r>=expand("%:p:h")<cr>/
" Return to last edit position when opening files (You want this!)
autocmd BufReadPost *
      \ if line("'\"") > 0 && line("'\"") <= line("$") |
      \   exe "normal! g`\"" |
      \ endif
"}}}


"SingleCompile {{{
nmap <F10> :SCCompile<cr>:cw<CR> 
nmap <F11> :SCCompileRun<CR> 
let g:tex_pdf_map_keys = 0
" au FileType tex inoremap <silent> <F10> <Esc>:BuildTexPdf<CR>
autocmd FileType tex inoremap <buffer> <F10> <Esc>:SCCompileAF -shell-escape <CR>:cw<CR> 
"}}}



"Syntastic {{{
set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}
set statusline+=%*
let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0
let g:syntastic_quiet_messages = { "regex": ['Do not use @ in LaTeX macro names',
                                  \ 'tikz.code.tex',
                                  \ "Don't use "]}
"}}}
```

## mwe.tex

```
\documentclass[a4paper,dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,color}
\definecolor{mp1}{RGB}{46,116,181}
\definecolor{mp2}{RGB}{255,127,14}
\definecolor{mp3}{RGB}{44,160,44}
\definecolor{mp4}{RGB}{214,39,40}
\definecolor{mp5}{RGB}{148,103,189}
\color{mp5}
\usepackage[ hmargin=20mm, vmargin=10mm ]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows, shadows}
% Define block styles for your flowchart
\tikzset{%
  block1/.style= {rectangle, draw, fill=mp1, text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners,
    minimum height=2em, text=white, font=\bfseries},
  block2/.style= {rectangle, draw, fill=mp2, text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners,
    minimum height=2em, text=white, font=\bfseries},
  line/.style = {draw, -latex, very thick, dashed},
  shadowed/.style={preaction={transform canvas={shift={(1pt,-.5pt)}},draw=gray,very thick, dashed}}
}
\title{MWE}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section*{S}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
   H Known
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thnaks.